# How to temporarily disable `xss-lock`?

Tags: linux

I have configured my i3wm to run `xss-lock --transfer-sleep-lock -- i3lock --nofork`.

There are times when I need to disable it and have the machine unlocked.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: `killall xxs-lock`

Comment: I tried the same earlier but could not re-enable `xss-lock` afterward for a reason that I do not remember. This time, I could [finally achieve](https://github.com/myTerminal/dotfiles/commit/ff358fb3022ef8098256983cb9a5955c87a72b95) what I wanted. Thank you!